# No "Server Default" option available in MySQL Workbench when creating a new table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am new to MySQL Workbench, just experimenting. I created a schema first. called wp_CPB
And then set that schema as default schema

then i right click "table"->create table, the in the UI, under the "Engine" option, i see InnoDB, NoCluster, Memory, CSV..etc, but I don't see "Server Default"

and i checked some tutorial online+youTube, in the UI they are showing, there is an option called "Server Default"

And this is the error message I am getting.

```
Executing:
CREATE TABLE `wp_cpb`.`new_table` (
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')
ENGINE = InnoDB' at line 2
SQL Statement:
CREATE TABLE `wp_cpb`.`new_table` (
)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Don't know why I am getting this error.

Comment: You cannot create a table without columns. PS: it makes no sense to choose "server default" - choose what satisfies your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Don't choose an engine and it will use the default, and add some columns to your table to avoid that error.

I agree that "Engine" should not be blank, and it should either say "Server Default" as it did in the past, fail and not use a default, or it should pre-select the actual default. Please file a bug report at http://bugs.mysql.com/ (the same applies to "Default Collation" when creating a Schema).